# hava jsp MyFaces Tomahawk Captha problems

Tags: captcha, myfaces, tomahawk

I have a website for a hiking club that has recently been spammed by automated registrations from some bot. There is human step involved in activations but the large number of nonsens registrations is annoying me.
In order to stop that from happening I added a CAPTCHA function. It worked great in my windows dev environment, but less so on the CentOS 5.4 64bit server. It generates this illegible image that makes no sense. What could the problem be?

Im using Myfaces 2.1.11 and Tomahawk2 1.1.14.

[Click here to see](http://www.spore.co.za/spore/register/register.jsf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out, its a font issue. Using [this link](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/xref/org/apache/myfaces/custom/captcha/CAPTCHARenderer.html) we found a reference to [this code](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/xref/org/apache/myfaces/custom/captcha/util/CAPTCHAImageGenerator.html). On line 61 its clear they use Arial, which is a truetype font and not installed by default on the CentOS server.